# Is this Patent Application withdrawn? - Status is unclear

Tags: us20010032084

I cannot determine if [this patent application](http://www.google.com/patents/US20010032084) has terminated or still under review.
The law firm that initially handled it on behalf of Ricoh Co. Ltd. (in Japan) in the US said it was an old patent and had no more records for this patent. Does this mean this patent is no longer under review?

Answer (score 1):

By looking this application up in the USPTO's Public PAIR database you can see that it went abandoned for lack of a response in 2005.

[image]